# Blogger JSON API add a post

Tags: java, android, api, request, blogger

I want to add post to my blog using Blogger API. I successfully got rights to use Blogger API and activated them in Google API console. I used [this](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/tasks/oauth-and-tasks-on-android#account) tutorial to obtain access_token. I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8067467/how-often-do-google-auth-tokens-expire-on-android-or-how-not-to-bother-grandm) , so before ever request I obtain new request_token.

When I make first request to add post, I got en error: **401 "message": "Invalid Credentials", "location": "Authorization"**.

When I make second request to add post with new token, I got error: **403 "message": "Daily Limit Exceeded. Please sign up"**

Code for my request is:

```
final JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
obj.put("id", mUserID);

final JSONObject requestBody = new JSONObject();
requestBody.put("kind", "blogger#post");
requestBody.put("blog", obj);
requestBody.put("title", msg[0]);
requestBody.put("content", msg[0] + " " + msg[1]);

final HttpPost request = new HttpPost("https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/" +   mUserID + "/posts");
request.addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + mToken);
request.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
request.setEntity(new StringEntity(requestBody.toString()));
final HttpResponse response = mHttpClient.execute(request);

final HttpEntity ent = response.getEntity();
Log.i(SocialPoster.LOG, EntityUtils.toString(ent));
ent.consumeContent();
```

**UPDATE**
Solution was found: simply adding "?key={MY_API_KEY}" to request's URL solved the problem

Comment: Your problem really helped me a lot, sincerely thanks for your question and answer

Comment: Are you using DefaultHttpClient or HttpClient

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Tutorial site you linked states

> "The API Key is mandatory as it identifies your application and therefore allows the API to deduct quota and use the quota rules defined for your project. You need to specify the API Key on your Tasks service Object."

```
useTasksAPI(String accessToken) {
  // Setting up the Tasks API Service
  HttpTransport transport = AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport();
  AccessProtectedResource accessProtectedResource = new GoogleAccessProtectedResource(accessToken);
  Tasks service = new Tasks(transport, accessProtectedResource, new JacksonFactory());
  service.accessKey = INSERT_YOUR_API_KEY;
  service.setApplicationName("Google-TasksSample/1.0");

  // TODO: now use the service to query the Tasks API
}
```

Sounds to me like you are missing the API key, using it wrong, misplaced it in your code or supplied it to the service in the wrong way.

I haven't looked over the code here, but this is Google's sample code for what you are trying to do. Test your API key with [this code.](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/source/browse/tasks-android-sample/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/tasks/android/TasksSample.java?repo=samples)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I tried to add "?key=<MY_API_KEY>" to request's url and it works =)

Comment: awesome, glad to be at service :)